# How Can I remove repeated files from input file (Angular)

Tags: angular, file, file-upload

I'm doing an webApp and it has a page to upload some files, I have a different input file for each file, I can add  files to the array of files from, the problem is if the user select a file from the same input file twice, it will have 2 different files for the same type of file, How Can I remove the first file of that input if the user already upload a file from it, I just need one file for each input?

this is what I got

in my template:

```
<input type="file" id="file3" (change)="onSelectCartaTrabajo($event)" />  
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlex="50" fxLayoutGap="30px">
    <label for="file3">
      <span class="material-icons icon-upload"> upload </span> Seleccionar
      archivo
    </label>
    <span class="fileName" *ngIf="CartaDeTrabajo" fxFlex="50">{{
      CartaDeTrabajo
    }}</span>
  </div>

    <p class="pl-1">
    <fa-icon class="faCaretRight mr-4" [icon]="faCaretRight"></fa-icon
    >Declaración de renta
  </p>
  <input
    type="file"
    id="file2"
    (change)="onDeclaracionDeRentaChange($event)"/>
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlex="50" fxLayoutGap="30px">
    <label for="file2">
      <span class="material-icons icon-upload"> upload </span> Seleccionar
      archivo
    </label>
    <span class="fileName" *ngIf="declaracionRenta" fxFlex="50">{{
      declaracionRenta
    }}</span>
</div>
```

in my ts file

```
async onDeclaracionDeRentaChange(event: any) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.otrosIngresos = file.name;
    this.declaracionFile = await this.fileToBase64(file);
    this.declaracionFileFileFormat = this.declaracionFile.split(';base64,')[1];

    const declaracionToSave = {
      idTypeDoc: 'e87979cd-dbee-42b2-93f6-ae52306a34a0',
      fileName: file.name,
      fileExtension: file.type,
      fileData: this.declaracionFileFileFormat,
    };

 async onSelectCartaTrabajo(event: any) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
    this.CartaDeTrabajo = file.name;
    this.cartaTrabajoFile = await this.fileToBase64(file);
    this.cartaTrabajoFileFormat = this.comprobantePagoFile.split(';base64,')[1];

    const cartaTrabajoToSave = {
      fileName: file.name,
      fileExtension: file.type,
      fileData: this.cartaTrabajoFileFormat,
    };

    this.listFileData.push(cartaTrabajoToSave);
    this.listFileData.pop();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the old value of the `fileInput`

Inside your `onSelectCartaTrabajo` method

```
onSelectCartaTrabajo(event: any){
    //do all stuff if valid then do the below
    event.target.value = ''; //or null
}
```

Or you can just add a `clickEvent` to your fileInput and set the value to null on each click, so your html would look like below.

```
<input #fileInput3 type="file" id="file3"(click)="fileInput3.value = null" (change)="onSelectCartaTrabajo($event)" />
```

this will always set the old of `#fileInput3` value to `null`, instead of in HTML you can also create a method and call it on `(click)` and pass the `$event and set the value to` null`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have a doubt, When is the older file removed from the array?

Comment: `event.target.value =  null` will always remove last value of the fileInput so you won't have   2 files in same input anymore, only the newly selected file will be there.

Comment: I tried the approach of setting the value of the file to null in my html but it gave me the error of "undefined"

Comment: It's not working, the array still has the old files that I have selected before

Comment: What do you actually want, I'm confused now!!

Comment: if you are sure that `this.listFileData` has already 2 values then you can just replace first item by doing `this.listFileData[0] = cartaTrabajoToSave`

Comment: I have resolve the problem, I add the file  to the array  when the form is submitted and not on the change event, doing it that way, only one file per input is added